# How do i change the order of this list with something i can input into the console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

<s>Yellow block-quote has been answered, see EDIT for followup question.</s> All Solved!

> I have a list that looks like this in HTML
>
> ```
> <div class="verticalSection verticalSection-extrabottompadding">
>   <h2 class="sectionTitle">
>   Library Order
>   </h2>
>   <div class="paperList viewOrderList">
>       <div class="listItem viewItem" data-viewid="9d7ad6afe9afa2dab1a2f6e00ad28fa6">
>       <div class="listItem viewItem" data-viewid="9ec840fc98bc99fab0bc952ee46828ad">
>       <div class="listItem viewItem" data-viewid="8860bba0ebc5d09e4d27fd85301c257b">
>       <div class="listItem viewItem" data-viewid="7e64e319657a9516ec78490da03edccb">
>       <div class="listItem viewItem" data-viewid="b7a798670696afa9a252916ed4f11f47">
>       <div class="listItem viewItem" data-viewid="c08a027359459c36152044a7dca3df81">
>       </div>
>   </div>   What can i input into console to change the order of those? lets say i want
>
> .listItem.viewItem data-viewid="7e64e319657a9516ec78490da03edccb"
> ```
>
> To go above
>
> ```
> .listItem.viewItem data-viewid="9d7ad6afe9afa2dab1a2f6e00ad28fa6"
> ```
>
> How do i do that? my knowledge in the matter is very limited but by
>   spending some time on google i think it can be done with this JQuery
>
> ```
> $('.listItem.viewItem').insertAfter('.listItem.viewItem'); But then the class listItem.viewItem also has the data-viewid attached to
> ```
>
> it so with my limited knowledge thats where I'm stuck at the moment as
>   i don't know how to format the command properly.

**EDIT:**

How would the code look if i wanted to set the list in a specific way without the need of the code to be dependent on the another values? lets say i want this specific list:

```
1. 9d7ad6afe9afa2dab1a2f6e00ad28fa6

2. 9ec840fc98bc99fab0bc952ee46828ad

3. 8860bba0ebc5d09e4d27fd85301c257b

4. b7a798670696afa9a252916ed4f11f47

5. c08a027359459c36152044a7dca3df81

6. 7e64e319657a9516ec78490da03edccb
```

And each time i input the code into the console the values would be put in that exact order no matter what the order was before. **What would that code look like?**

I assume something like this?

```
$('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="9d7ad6afe9afa2dab1a2f6e00ad28fa6"]') additional command here
$('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="9ec840fc98bc99fab0bc952ee46828ad"]') additional command here
$('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="8860bba0ebc5d09e4d27fd85301c257b"]') additional command here
$('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="b7a798670696afa9a252916ed4f11f47"]') additional command here
$('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="c08a027359459c36152044a7dca3df81"]') additional command here
$('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="7e64e319657a9516ec78490da03edccb"]') additional command here
```

Comment: First off you need valid html to do DOM-Manipulations -> all your div-elements in .paperList are not closed

Comment: It is closed at the source, i was just typing that html as i saw it from the developer tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

```
let ids = ['9d7ad6afe9afa2dab1a2f6e00ad28fa6',
    '9ec840fc98bc99fab0bc952ee46828ad',
    '8860bba0ebc5d09e4d27fd85301c257b',
    'b7a798670696afa9a252916ed4f11f47',
    'c08a027359459c36152044a7dca3df81',
    '7e64e319657a9516ec78490da03edccb'];

for (let i = ids.length - 1; i > 0; i--) { 
    $('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="'+ids[i-1]+'"]').insertBefore('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="'+ids[i]+'"]');
}
```

Comment: How would the code look if i wanted to set the list in a specific way without the need of the code to be dependent on the another values if you know what i mean? lets say i want this list

1. 7e64e319657a9516ec78490da03edccb
2. 9d7ad6afe9afa2dab1a2f6e00ad28fa6
3. b7a798670696afa9a252916ed4f11f47 
And each time i input the code into the console the values would be put in the correct order set by the code no matter what the order was before.

Comment: I modified the answer

Comment: Is it possible to make it able to run more than one time? as of now if i try to run it again i get this message "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'ids' has already been declared
    at <anonymous>:1:1"

Comment: instead of 'let' use 'var'

Comment: You're the best! really appreciate the help. And yes, that did work.

Answer (score 0):

Well i did it, and this is probably a really ugly way to do it but it works.

```
/* LIBRARY ORDER - List 9d7ad6afe9afa2dab1a2f6e00ad28fa6 First */
$('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="9d7ad6afe9afa2dab1a2f6e00ad28fa6"]').insertBefore('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="9ec840fc98bc99fab0bc952ee46828ad"]').insertBefore('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="8860bba0ebc5d09e4d27fd85301c257b"]').insertBefore('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="b7a798670696afa9a252916ed4f11f47"]').insertBefore('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="c08a027359459c36152044a7dca3df81"]').insertBefore('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="7e64e319657a9516ec78490da03edccb"]');

/* LIBRARY ORDER - List 9ec840fc98bc99fab0bc952ee46828ad 2nd */
$('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="9ec840fc98bc99fab0bc952ee46828ad"]').insertBefore('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="8860bba0ebc5d09e4d27fd85301c257b"]').insertBefore('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="b7a798670696afa9a252916ed4f11f47"]').insertBefore('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="c08a027359459c36152044a7dca3df81"]').insertBefore('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="7e64e319657a9516ec78490da03edccb"]');

/* LIBRARY ORDER - List 8860bba0ebc5d09e4d27fd85301c257b 3rd */
$('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="8860bba0ebc5d09e4d27fd85301c257b"]').insertBefore('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="b7a798670696afa9a252916ed4f11f47"]').insertBefore('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="c08a027359459c36152044a7dca3df81"]').insertBefore('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="7e64e319657a9516ec78490da03edccb"]');

/* LIBRARY ORDER - List b7a798670696afa9a252916ed4f11f47 4th */
$('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="b7a798670696afa9a252916ed4f11f47"]').insertBefore('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="c08a027359459c36152044a7dca3df81"]').insertBefore('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="7e64e319657a9516ec78490da03edccb"]');

/* LIBRARY ORDER - List c08a027359459c36152044a7dca3df81 5th & 7e64e319657a9516ec78490da03edccb 6th */
$('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="c08a027359459c36152044a7dca3df81"]').insertBefore('.listItem.viewItem[data-viewid="7e64e319657a9516ec78490da03edccb"]');
```